# Deserialize generic object using Kotlin Serialization

Tags: kotlin, generics, serialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to replace Gson library by [kotlin serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) to handle JSON serialization/deserialization.

I am facing some issues to deserialize generic objects I have setup a simple example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
@Serializable
data class ContentMessageDto<T>(
    val method: String,
    val content: T
)

@Serializable
private data class DummyObjectNonNullProperties(
    val value: Int,
    @SerialName("aaa") val someProp: String,
    val bbb: Boolean,
    val ccc: Double
)

interface MyParser {
    fun <T> parseContentMessage(
        json: String
    ): ContentMessageDto<T>
}

class MyParserImpl(private val jsonSerialization: Json) : MyParser {
    override fun <T> parseContentMessage(json: String): ContentMessageDto<T> {
        return jsonSerialization.decodeFromString<ContentMessageDto<T>>(json)
    }

}

fun main() {
    println("start processing...")
    val jsonToParse = """
                {
                    "method":"get",
                    "content":{
                        "value":345,
                        "aaa": "some string",
                        "bbb": true,
                        "ccc": 23.4
                    }
                }""".trimIndent()

    val parser:MyParser = MyParserImpl(Json)

    val result = parser.parseContentMessage<DummyObjectNonNullProperties>(jsonToParse)

    println("result -> $result")

}
```

But when I run the main method, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only KClass supported as classifier, got T
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.kclass(Platform.common.kt:102)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:52)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.builtinSerializerOrNull$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:79)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializerByKTypeImpl$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:69)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:54)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source)
```

But I am not sure why. Can someone provide me an explanation and if possible some tips on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 6):

It would have worked if you've simply done:

```kotlin
val result = Json.decodeFromString<ContentMessageDto<DummyObjectNonNullProperties>>(jsonToParse)
```

But with all this wrapping, type information about `T` was lost. The problem is that you can't simply use `reified` generics here, cause `inline` functions can't be non-final.

Possible workarounds:

1. Define `parseContentMessage` as extension function so that it could have `inline` modifier (and `T` could be `reified`):

```kotlin
interface MyParser {
    val jsonSerialization: Json
}

inline fun<reified T> MyParser.parseContentMessage(json: String): ContentMessageDto<T> {
    return jsonSerialization.decodeFromString(json)
}

class MyParserImpl(override val jsonSerialization: Json) : MyParser

//Usage will be the same
```

2. Manually pass serializer for `T` into `parseContentMessage`:

```kotlin
interface MyParser {
    fun <T> parseContentMessage(json: String, contentSerializer: KSerializer<T>): ContentMessageDto<T>
}

class MyParserImpl(private val jsonSerialization: Json) : MyParser {
    override fun <T> parseContentMessage(json: String, contentSerializer: KSerializer<T>): ContentMessageDto<T> {
        return jsonSerialization.decodeFromString(ContentMessageDto.serializer(contentSerializer), json)
    }
}

//Usage:
val result = parser.parseContentMessage(jsonToParse, DummyObjectNonNullProperties.serializer())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know is I call directly it would have worked. When I find some time I will try your suggestions

Comment: What if `T` could be also a `String` or a `Boolean`?